# Write XML with XDocument doesn't add XElements probably

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to C# and Linq. I am trying to write my Dictionary to file as XML. Therefore I use a foreach loop add all XElements to a root XElement. This is added to the document. But it does only add the last iteration of my loop to the document. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
    public void ToXml(string xmlFile)
    {
        //Dictionary used: Values
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
        XElement xRoot = new XElement("RootElement");
        doc.Add(xRoot);
        Dictionary<double, double[]>.KeyCollection keys = Values.Keys;

        foreach(double key in keys)
        {
            XElement inner = new XElement("InnerElement",
                new XAttribute("value", key),
                new XElement("TestValue1", Values[key][0]),
                new XElement("Testvalue2", Values[key][1]),
                new XElement("TestValue3", Values[key][2]),
                new XElement("TestValue4", Values[key][3]),
                new XElement("TestValue5", Values[key][4]),
                new XElement("TestValue6", Values[key][5]));

            xRoot.Add(inner);
        }
        doc.Save(xmlFile);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RootElement> 
    <InnerElement value="400"> 
        <TestValue1>0</TestValue1> 
        <Testvalue2>0</Testvalue2> 
        <TestValue3>200</TestValue3> 
        <TestValue4>0</TestValue4> 
        <TestValue5>100</TestValue5> 
        <TestValue6>491</TestValue6> 
    </InnerElement> 
</RootElement>
```

Comment: Code seems ok, please check that `Values` does not contain only one key.

Comment: Yes you were right, forgot about an input mistake. Thanks.